# R Shiny - Intersect two or more columns into one based on user selected input

Tags: r, shiny

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48084715/r-shiny-add-new-column-to-dataframe-based-on-user-selected-input) post, users were able to select a column from the dataframe using a dropdown, select some values to compare from that column using some checkboxes, and add a new column to the same frame reflecting the comparisons that they wanted to make.

I realize I need something more complex, where users are able to select multiple columns from a dataframe and generate a similar result in the dataframe. Here is an illustration of the more complex final table. In this example, the user has selected the Author.Name and Fav.Color columns to look at and have selected the populated values: Bob, Tom, Green, Red. This will then produce two new columns, one comparing Green vs Red with Bob and the other with Tom.

```
Project.ID      Author.ID    Author.Name    Fav.Color   Bob_GreenvRed   Tom_GreenvRed
Test_Project1    1234            Bob        Green       Green            NA
Test_Project1    2345            Jane       Blue        NA               NA   
Test_Project1    2687            Bob        Blue        NA               NA
Test_Project1    8765            Tom        Red         NA           Red
```

I've modified my code (shown below) to allow for selection of multiple columns and values across them but can't seem to wrap my head around the 'set' problem with column generation. I've tried my best to apply my understanding from the answer that @Bertil Baron has kindly provided but I'm not quite there yet. I believe the issue resides somewhere in the `finalTable` reactive.

```
    server <- function(input, output, session) {

      # update datatable
      project <- reactive({
        if(input$viewType == "Projects"){
          projectDT <- read.table(header = TRUE,
      text = "Project.ID,Author.ID,Author.Name,Fav.Color
    Test_Project1,1234,Bob,Green
    Test_Project1,2345,Jane,Blue
    Test_Project1,2687,Bob,Blue
    Test_Project1,8765,Tom,Red",
                                  sep = ",")

          #replace spaces with dots in headers
          names(projectDT) <- gsub(" ", ".", names(projectDT))
          projectDT
        }
    })

        observeEvent({input$addCol},{
    insertUI(
      selector = "#addCol", 
      where = "afterEnd", 
      ui = div(               
        uiOutput(paste0("showMeta",input$addCol)),  
        uiOutput(paste0("showVal",input$addCol))    
      )
    )
    lapply(1:input$addCol, function(idx){ #apply for as many columns as you want
      output[[paste0("showMeta",idx)]] <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId =  paste0("metalab",idx),
                    label =  "Metadata Label:",
                    choices =  c(" ", unique(as.vector(colnames(project())))),
                    selected = input[[paste0("metalab",idx)]], 
                    multiple = TRUE, 
                    selectize = TRUE
        )
      })
    })
    lapply(1:input$addCol, function(idx){
      output[[paste0("showVal",idx)]] <- renderUI({
        req(input$addCol >= idx) 
        labelList <- input[[paste0("metalab",idx)]] 
        choiceList <- NULL               
        for(aLabel in labelList){
          choiceList <- cbind(choiceList, as.vector(unlist(project()[aLabel])))  
        }
        checkboxGroupInput(paste0("metaval",idx),
                           "Metadata Value:",
                           choices = unique(as.vector(choiceList)),    #flatten frame to vector and grab only unique values
                           selected = input[[paste0("metaval",idx)]]
        )
      })
    })
  })

  #Update the table with comparison columns
  finalTable <- reactive({
    projectDT <- project()
    dta <- NULL           
    if(input$addCol > 0) {      
      dta <- lapply(seq(input$addCol), function(idx){ 
        if(!is.null(input[[paste0("metalab", idx)]]) &&    
           input[[paste0("metalab",idx)]] != " "){      
          labelList <- input[[paste0("metalab",idx)]] 
          choiceList <- input[[paste0("metaval", idx)]]
          for(aLabel in labelList){
            ifelse(projectDT[[aLabel]] %in% input[[paste0("metaval", idx)]], as.character(projectDT[[aLabel]]),"NA")
           }
        }
      })
      names(dta) <- sapply(seq(input$addCol),function(idx){   #add names to column
        paste0("Compare",idx,"_",paste0(input[[paste0("metaval",idx)]],collapse = "vs"))
      })
      dta <- as.data.frame(dta[!sapply(dta,is.null)]) 
    }
    if(!is.null(dta) && 
       !is.null(projectDT) &&
       nrow(dta) == nrow(projectDT)){
      projectDT <- cbind(projectDT,dta)
    }
    return(projectDT)
  })

  #Display the updated table
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(finalTable(), extensions = c('FixedColumns', 'Buttons'),
             options = list(
             dom = 'Bfrtip',
             scrollX = TRUE, buttons = c('csv', I('colvis'))
         ))
    }) 

  #Download file
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$lab, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(as.matrix(finalTable()), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! I feel like I'm almost there but just need a final push!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Or as close as I can get to it for now.

Following the example above, it now asks the user how they want to subset the data first (by Author.Name) and whatever values, before further subsetting by the Fav.Color values. Hope this helps if anyone is having issues with this!

```
      observeEvent({input$addCol},{
    insertUI(
      selector = "#addCol", #some string to determine the element(s) relative to which you want to insert your UI object.
      where = "afterEnd", #where UI object should go relative to the selector
      ui = div(               #object you want to insert, if multiple, wrap in div
        uiOutput(paste0("subsetCheckbox", input$addCol)), #subset box
        uiOutput(paste0("showSubmeta", input$addCol)),
        uiOutput(paste0("showSubval", input$addCol)),
        uiOutput(paste0("showMeta",input$addCol)),  #showMeta selector
        uiOutput(paste0("showVal",input$addCol))    #showVal selector
      )
    )
    lapply(1:input$addCol, function(idx){
      output[[paste0("subsetCheckbox", idx)]] <- renderUI({
        checkboxInput('subset', strong("Subset"), value = FALSE)
      })
    })
      lapply(1:input$addCol, function(idx){ #apply for as many columns as you want
      output[[paste0("showSubmeta",idx)]] <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId =  paste0("submeta",idx),
                    label =  "Subset Label:",
                    choices =  c(" ", unique(as.vector(colnames(project())))),
                    selected = input[[paste0("submeta",idx)]]
        )
      })
    })
      lapply(1:input$addCol, function(idx){
        output[[paste0("showSubval",idx)]] <- renderUI({
          req(input$addCol >= idx) 
          checkboxGroupInput(paste0("subval",idx),
                             "Subset Value:",
                             choices = unique(as.vector(unlist(project()[[input[[paste0("submeta",idx)]]]]))),
                             selected = input[[paste0("subval",idx)]]
          )
        })
      })
    #insert metadata selection menus
    lapply(1:input$addCol, function(idx){ 
      output[[paste0("showMeta",idx)]] <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId =  paste0("metalab",idx),
                    label =  "Metadata Label:",
                    choices =  c(" ", unique(as.vector(colnames(project())))),
                    selected = input[[paste0("metalab",idx)]]
        )
      })
    })
    lapply(1:input$addCol, function(idx){
      output[[paste0("showVal",idx)]] <- renderUI({
        req(input$addCol >= idx) 
        checkboxGroupInput(paste0("metaval",idx),
                           "Metadata Value:",
                           choices = unique(as.vector(unlist(project()[[input[[paste0("metalab",idx)]]]]))),
                           selected = input[[paste0("metaval",idx)]]
        )
      })
    })
  })


  #Update the table with comparison columns
  finalTable <- reactive({
    projectDT <- project()
    dta <- NULL             #initiate an empty dataframe
    if(input$addCol > 0) {       #if button has been clicked
      dta <- lapply(seq(input$addCol), function(idx){ 
        #subset logic
        if(input$subset == TRUE && !is.null(input[[paste0("submeta", idx)]]) &&    
           input[[paste0("submeta",idx)]] != " " && !is.null(input[[paste0("metalab", idx)]]) &&    
           input[[paste0("metalab",idx)]] != " " ){
          ifelse(projectDT[[input[[paste0("submeta", idx)]]]] %in% input[[paste0("subval", idx)]], 
                 ifelse(projectDT[[input[[paste0("metalab", idx)]]]] %in% input[[paste0("metaval", idx)]], 
                        as.character(projectDT[[input[[paste0("metalab", idx)]]]]),"NA"), "NA")
        }
        #no subset logic
        else if(!is.null(input[[paste0("metalab", idx)]]) &&    #if metalab isn't null
           input[[paste0("metalab",idx)]] != " "){      #if metalab isn't " ", add values into column by magic
          ifelse(projectDT[[input[[paste0("metalab", idx)]]]] %in% input[[paste0("metaval", idx)]], as.character(projectDT[[input[[paste0("metalab", idx)]]]]),"NA")
        }
      })
      #sapply - apply function to each element of a list in turn and return a VECTOR
      names(dta) <- sapply(seq(input$addCol),function(idx){   #add names to column
        paste0("Compare",idx,"_",paste0(input[[paste0("metaval",idx)]],collapse = "vs"))
      })
      dta <- as.data.frame(dta[!sapply(dta,is.null)]) 
    }
    if(!is.null(dta) && 
       !is.null(projectDT) &&
       nrow(dta) == nrow(projectDT)){
      projectDT <- cbind(projectDT,dta)
    }
    return(projectDT)
  })
```